# Object resizing, storing variable and resizing from previous size in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have written a script to resize an object by clicking on it and dragging.

The problem I'm having is that when I stop dragging and click on the object again, it snaps back to its initial size. I understand that what I have to do is store the size which it was previously resized to, and "start from this size" but I am struggling to get my head round the logic for this.

I think I have to add a bool `hasBeenDragged` which will be made true if the `amountDragged` variable `!= 0` `onMouseUp` ... and say in the update function, if `hasBeenDragged = true && dragging = true` - then this is the bit I'm struggling with.

I need it to calculate the `amountDragged` based on the previous amount too, but I cant get my head round how to write that..

Any help with the logic would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Heres my script:

```
public class DragScalingScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool dragging = false;
    public Vector3 currentMousePosition;
    public Vector3 dragStartingPoint;
    public Vector3 temp;
    public float amountDragged;
    private float clampedAmountDragged;

    private void Awake()
    {
        amountDragged = 100.0f;
    }

    // where ever the object is clicked becomes dragStartingPoint
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        dragStartingPoint = (Input.mousePosition);
    }

    // if object is dragged, dragging becomes true
    //where ever the position of the mouse drag goes is tracked and stored as currentMousePosition
    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        dragging = true;
        currentMousePosition = (Input.mousePosition);
    }

    // when mouse button is released, dragging becomes false
    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        dragging = false;
    }

    // when dragging:
    private void Update()
    {
        if (dragging == true)
        {
            //find the distance between the dragStartingPoint and currentMousePosition and store in amountDragged variable
            amountDragged = Vector3.Distance(currentMousePosition, dragStartingPoint);

            // set minimum and maximum drag amount and store in clampedAmountDragged variable
            clampedAmountDragged = Mathf.Clamp(amountDragged, 100f, 300f);

            // set amountDragged to clampedAmount to apply minimum and maximum
            amountDragged = clampedAmountDragged;

            temp = transform.localScale;
            temp.x = amountDragged / 100;
            temp.y = amountDragged / 100;

            //make scale of object equal to temp variable
            transform.localScale = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure about the exact calculation but in `OnMouseDown` additionally store the current scale like

```
private Vector3 startScale;

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    dragStartingPoint = Input.mousePosition;

    startScale = transform.localScale;
}
```

And then multiply by this value while scaling using [`Vector3.Scale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Scale.html)

```
// No need to get the current localScale here as this is a scale factor now
temp = new Vector3(amountDragged / 100f, amountDragged / 100f, 1);

// Vector3.Scale multiplies both vectors component wise
transform.localScale = Vector3.Scale(temp, startScale);
// Basically the same as
//transform.localScale = new Vector3(temp.x * startScale.x, temp.y * startScale.y, temp.z * startScale.z);
```

---

In general you go a bit redundant here. I wouldn't use `Update` at all but simply directly do the stuff in [`OnMouseDrag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDrag.html) not using the `dragging` flag since amyway

> `OnMouseDrag` is called every frame while the mouse is down.

so simply put the code here

```
// This gets called while dragging the mouse 
private void OnMouseDrag()
{
    currentMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

    //find the distance between the dragStartingPoint and currentMousePosition and store in amountDragged variable
    amountDragged = Vector3.Distance(currentMousePosition, dragStartingPoint);

    // set minimum and maximum drag amount and store in clampedAmountDragged variable
    clampedAmountDragged = Mathf.Clamp(amountDragged, 100f, 300f);

    // set amountDragged to clampedAmount to apply minimum and maximum
    amountDragged = clampedAmountDragged;

    var temp = new Vector3(amountDragged / 100f, amountDragged / 100f, 1);

    //make scale of object equal to temp variable
    transform.localScale = Vector3.Scale(temp, startScale);
}
```

---

Also note that currently this only allows to scale the object bigger. There is no way for reverting ;)

---

*Typed on the phone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Shrinking behaviour can only happen during the initial drag. Because it is calculating the distance between the initial drag point and where you have dragged it to, you are able to reduce this distance. After you release it, the moment you click it again, it just goes back to initial size. 

I have realised now that this code will not work for what I want it to do, if I want it to be able to properly resize both ways (make larger and make smaller) then I need to calculate the distance from the centre of the shape and not from the initialDragPoint. Woild you agree with that?